# Best practice to add javascript functions in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using rails and I have lot of javascript functions,I don't want to put them in application.js. Is it fine to move them to different js files based on the layouts ? so that the each time when I load, it will not load all of them. is there any other best practice is available for these kind of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general we follow the following rule,

- If the code is used by many controller views, put it in the application.js
- If the code is specific to a particular controller view, create a js file for that controller and put it in that. It would be easy to identify if you follow a naming convention for the js file. For a article controller, create a js as article.js

Talking in terms of performance, in rails 3.1 we have [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) that compresses and packages js files. Prior to that we have many tools available that compresses and packages the js files. Example [asset packager](http://synthesis.sbecker.net/pages/asset_packager)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you want to write your own bootstraper. Yes, this is a good idea (although it has nothing to do with rails). For example using jQuery function `$.getScript()` you can dynamically load only those scripts you need (of course you'll need some additional scripting to make this process automatic).

Although there are two schools: one which tends to compress as much data as it can into one big file (together with browser caching it is very nice way) and the other with bootstrapers - loading only those scripts you actually need.

On the other hand, if your scripts are not as big as (for example) jQuery itself, then it really doesn't matter, imho.